# How to use Python library in SQL platform without using Databricks?

Tags: python, sql, azure, databricks

I have developed a Python library that is installed on a Databricks cluster and is used to apply a few functions on delta tables:

- Import library into a notebook
- Read required data from delta tables
- Run python functions on the data and store results in a delta table

I need to run the same python codes in an Azure environment that doesn't have Databricks workspace. The client doesn't use Azure Databricks and all tables are SQL tables stored in Azure SQL database.

Is there any way or service that I can use the same python library in a SQL platform without using Databricks (e.g Data Factory, Azure Function)? Especially, any service that supports Spark.

It is not possible to write all codes in SQL language so I need to use the python library.

Comment: Python has nothing to do with Databricks. If it's installed on a machine, you can run Python scripts, provided you install the packages used by that script. A *Jupyter Notebook* though isn't a Python script, it's a file that's only understood by Jupyter Notebook server and compatible products. It's only needed for interactive work, not scripts that run in the background. You can extract the Python parts into a `Python file and run them like any other Python script though.

Comment: `any way or service` what do you mean? Almost all services support Python. Most Linux VMs have Python installed. Azure Functions has [a Python flavor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators) too. If you don't use Databricks-specific packages you'll be able to run any Python script you want. Azure SDK is available for Python and most services have a Python package as well

Comment: If you want to manage Data Lake files for example, [Use Python to manage directories and files in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python?tabs=azure-ad) shows how to do it using Python. Most services include Python guides

Comment: Simple way , you can package your python module Pypy and use it anywhere you need . https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos.   Thanks. Spark functions have been used in the Python code. Is it still possible to use the services you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can add libraries by pip install on the instance or manually copy the package, specify the WHL e.g:

Copy
scripts\pip.exe install C:\Downloads\cntk-2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

- This only will work if you have SQL Server Machine Learning Services installed with the Python language option

more information on how to install python package in SQL Server [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/package-management/install-python-packages-standard-tools?view=sql-server-2017#add-a-python-package-on-sql-server)